# How to access CakePHP Shell Arguments?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a cake shell script. When I use some named arguments eg:

```
--username=world
```

how can I get the "username" param / value?

My code looks like this:

```
class InviteShell extends AppShell
{
//... here are my methods.

public function getOptionParser()
    {
        $parser = parent::getOptionParser();
        $parser->addArgument('username', array(
            'help' => 'Send E-Mail to which user?'
        ))->addOption('method', array(
            'short' => 'm',
            'help' => __('The specific method you want help on.')
        ))->description(__('Lookup doc block comments for classes in CakePHP'));
        return $parser;
    }

}
```

And what is the difference between argument and option? And also how can I read these options in my code?

The one thing that works is I can read the $this->args array, but this is not named. All I can do is get the arg by index, eg.: $this->args[0]

I am using Cake 2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are positional values, options are prefixed values:

```
shell_method argument1 argument2 --optionA=value --optionB=value
```

So in your case `username` is a positional argument that will be looked up at position `0`, and `method` is a prefix option that can occour anywhere.

```
shell_method userA --method=methodX
shell_method --method=methodX userA
```

In both cases the `userA` value will be available in `$this->args[0]`, and the `methodX` value will be available in `$this->params['method']` or via `$this->param('method')`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Creating a Shell](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Adding arguments](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-arguments)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Adding options](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-options)**